# Is variable allocation really expensive in Ruby, or does it optimize chained string methods?

Tags: ruby, string, performance

I have the following method that I wrote for [Project Euler - Problem 36](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=36). All it does is add up all the numbers less than 1,000,000 that are palindromes in both base 10 and base 2.

```
def problem_36
  (1...1_000_000).select do |n|
    n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse && n.to_s(2) == n.to_s(2).reverse
  end
end
```

Now, this works and gives the correct result in just over 1 second. I wanted to get it under 1 second, so I decided I would reduce the number of times I was converting numbers to strings. So I made the following changes:

```
def problem_36
  (1...1_000_000).select do |n|
    base10 = n.to_s
    base2  = n.to_s(2)
    base10 == base10.reverse && base2 == base2.reverse
  end
end
```

The trouble is, this version actually runs about 50% *slower* than the original. So the question is this: is it really that slow to allocate those two variables? Or is Ruby optimizing the chained method calls?

Comment: And just to clarify, there was no real need to make the first version faster, I just wanted to see if I could. That just caused me to stumble across this seeming oddity.

Comment: Check out the [results on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4Seut)

Comment: My suspicion: The difference is in how the garbage collector handles nameless temporary objects versus objects stored in variables.

Comment: Also, what Ruby version are you using? 1.8.* has a lot of weird cases where performance nosedives because the interpreter can't optimize its way out of a paper bag.

Comment: Sorry, it is ruby 1.9.2 that I originally ran it on. But I see the issue in 1.8.7 as well.

Comment: A new [test run](http://ideone.com/ckpW8) that incorporates the information provided by @steenslag and @AShelly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line

```
n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse && n.to_s(2) == n.to_s(2).reverse
```

the second part is not executed if the first part is `false` (Ruby's `&&` operator short-circuits, [unlike its `&` counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487067/how-to-avoid-short-circuit-evaluation-on/487257#487257)). That saves a lot of calls to `to_s(2)`.

Comment: building on this, the first version does not do the base2 conversion unless n is a base10 palindrome, which i'd guess is less than 10% of the numbers. The 2nd version does the base2 conversion regardless. So try `base10==base10.reverse && (base2=n.to_s(2))==base2.reverse`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I didn't think about the fact that a lot of time I'm not calling `n.to_s(2)` because the first part of the `&&` fails. I'm gonna try @AShelly's suggestion and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

The usual Ruby performance rule is that if a program uses the built-in operations, it will be fast. If it doesn't, it will be slow.

Even though your second version may or may not do less converting, it executes three Ruby lines vs one.

I once read a large logfile.  In my first version, I kept an efficient linked list of the lines using Ruby code.

**1.** Time complexity: O(1).

I then changed it to just use `<<` and tack each new node onto the end of an Array.

**2.** Time complexity: O(N<sup>2</sup>), or at least O(N<sup>1 + ε</sup>)

The second version<sup>(1)</sup> was faster.

---

<sup>1. Obviously the implementation was expanding the array in chunks, so it wasn't fully quadratic, but still a lot more work than a linked list.</sup>

Comment: Linked Lists have been performing worse than auto-expanding arrays for ages in many languages, not just in Ruby.  *Especially* not in Ruby, where having a pointer is more expensive than in, say, C.

Comment: On the issue of linked list vs array performance check out this blog post: http://drmcawesome.com/rubyArrays - provides a good description of how arrays are implemented, and thus why they usually outperform linked lists.